# Error : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {xxxx} failed due to the following error: 80080005

Tags: asp.net

I am using My Company's Outlook account to send mails, but i got this error : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.

The Sendmail method is given below:

```
  public static void SendEmail(string _ToEmail, string _Subject, string _EmailBody)
  {
    oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem email = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)(oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
    email.Recipients.Add(_ToEmail);
    email.Subject = _Subject;
    email.Body = _EmailBody;
    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)email).Send();
  }
```

and also I added both Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll and office.dll to my solution.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

COM requires STA threads.  Ensure that you are instantiating the object on an STA thread.

Comment: this SO question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342160/asp-net-and-sta-com-objects